# RabbitMQ Message Consumption ID based (c# API)

Tags: c#, api, message-queue, rabbitmq

i would like to publish/produce a message with some message id, like each message has a particular id..

And at the consumer end i would like to retrieve the messages by prividing the ID.
suppose we have multiple consumers than each one should get only those messages which they requested through the message ids. (i hope i am clear enough).

Answer (score 2):

Although its not by design and its better to use a database for that there is a way to do this using rabbitmq:

**Publish a message with id:**

```
var message = "some message";
var messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };

using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    props.MessageId = messageId;

    byte[] messageBodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    channel.BasicPublish("", "queueName", true, props, messageBodyBytes);
}
```

**Get a message by id:**

```
var messageId = "id";
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };

using (var connection = _factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    var queueDeclareResponse = channel.QueueDeclare("queueName", true, true, false, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < queueDeclareResponse.MessageCount; i++)
    {
        var result = channel.BasicGet("queueName", false);
        var id = result.BasicProperties.MessageId;

        if (id == messageId)
        {
            var body = result.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            //Do something with the message

            channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After `channel` is disposed all messages that was not **acked** will requeue.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using a database for this.

alexis (rabbitmq)

Comment: Ok, i understood that i will have to involve database.
can you please elaborate little more on what i am suppose to do so that a begginer like me can understand.
Thanks For Replying.